# HTML: Is it always possible to remove table cell borders?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to remove the blue border around the cells of the following table. No matter what I do, the blue remains. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

[image: table image]

```
<html>
   <style type="text/css">
      #outerdiv{
         width: 140px; 
         height:185px;  
         overflow-x: auto; 
         overflow-y: hidden;
      }
      table{
         display: block;  
         width: 280px; 
         background-color: blue;
      }
      thead{
         max-width: 280px; 
         display: block; 
      }
      thead tr{
         height: 45px; 
         width: 280px;
      }
      thead tr td{
         width: 70px;
      }
      tbody{
         max-height: 140px; 
         display: block; 
         overflow-y: auto
      }
      tbody tr{
         height: 70px;
      }
      tbody tr td{
         width: 70px;
      }
      td{ 
         background-color: red;
         border:0px solid #D0D0D0 !important;
         margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         width: 70px;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <div id="outerdiv">
         <table >
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>>4</td>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>4</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>4</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3/td>
                  <td>4</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>4</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

If I set the border to say 10px:

```
td{ 
         background-color: red;
         border:10px solid #D0D0D0 !important;
         margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         width: 70px;
      }
```

You can see it set the border, but the blue remains. I need the blue gone, but not by setting it to red, by making the cells grow to fill the area.

[image: table image with gray border]

Comment: The table has a blue background - have you tried removing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, You're looking for `border-collapse`

**See example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/obcxg108/)**

And more information here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp

:)

Comment: Would any of the downvoters care to explain to me why you've downvoted? Just downvoting does not help anybody without some criticism

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing `background-color:blue` from table will help

```
`<html>
   <style type="text/css">
      #outerdiv{
         width: 140px; 
         height:185px;  
         overflow-x: auto; 
         overflow-y: hidden;
      }
      table{
         display: block;  
         width: 280px; 

      }
      thead{
         max-width: 280px; 
         display: block; 
      }
      thead tr{
         height: 45px; 
         width: 280px;
      }
      thead tr td{
         width: 70px;
      }
      tbody{
         max-height: 140px; 
         display: block; 
         overflow-y: auto
      }
      tbody tr{
         height: 70px;
      }
      tbody tr td{
         width: 70px;
      }
      td{ 
         background-color: red;
         border:0px solid #D0D0D0 !important;
         margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         width: 70px;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <div id="outerdiv">
         <table >
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>>4</td>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>4</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>4</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3/td>
                  <td>4</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>4</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>`
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Sneha, but I can't do it that way. Reason being this is just a subset of what I'm ultimately trying to do, so while removing the blue, will work in this case, It won't fix the problem in the long run.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: So describe the actual problem you are trying to solve instead of a theoretical one which doesn't even represent what you are trying to do.

Comment: I ultimately need to add a row separator that continuously connects, but with this border it will have breaks in it every cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(255,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(255,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(255,0,0,1);
```

Why not use `box-shadow`?

or

`outline: red solid thick;`

```
  td{ 
     background-color: red;
     outline: red solid thick;
     margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     width: 70px;
  }
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think your required functionality can be solved using border-collapse property.

Check below

```
table {
    display: block;
    width: 280px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

It will come like above: 
[image]